# How is the memory layout of a C/C++ program?

Tags: c++

I know that there are sections like Stack, Heap, Code and Data. Stack/Heap do they use the same section of memory as they can grow independently?
What is this code section? When I have a function is it a part of the stack or the code section? 
Also what is this initialized/uninitialized data segment?

Are there read only memory section available? When I have a const variable, what is actually happening is it that the compiler marks a memory section as read only or does it put into a read only memory section.

Where are static data kept? 
Where are global data kept?

Any good references/articles for the same?

I thought the memory sections and layout are OS independent and it has more to do with compiler. Doesn't Stack, Heap, Code, Data [Initialized, Uninitialized] segment occur in all the OS? When there is a static data, what is happening the compiler has understood it is static, what next, what will it do? It is the compiler which is managing the program and it should know what to do right? All compilers shouldn't they follow common standards?

Comment: +1 for the curiosity and enthusiasm - but you'd vastly improve the chances of getting concrete answers if you'd break it down into individual questions.

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if we understood why you want to know and (because it is very platform/compiler specific) what platform you are targeting. In general though the answer to these questions are not rellavent to a general C++ programmer (with exceptions like compiler/device driver writers), what is more important is object life span and how the different types of objects affect lifespan.

Answer (score 8):

There's very little that's actually definitive about C++ memory layouts. However, most modern OS's use a somewhat similar system, and the segments are separated based on permissions.

Code has execute permission. The other segments don't. In a Windows application, you can't just put some native code on the stack and execute. Linux offers the same functionality- it's in the x86 architecture.

Data is data that's part of the result (.exe, etc) but can't be written to. This section is basically where literals go. Only read permission in this section.

Those two segments are part of the resulting file. Stack and Heap are runtime allocated, instead of mapped off the hard drive.

Stack is essentially one, large (1MB or so, many compilers offer a setting for it) heap allocation. The compiler manages it for you.

Heap memory is memory that the OS returns to you through some process. Normally, heap is a heap (the data structure) of pointers to free memory blocks and their sizes. When you request one, it's given to you. Both read and write permissions here, but no execute.

There is read-only memory(ROM). However, this is just the Data section. You can't alter it at runtime. When you make a const variable, nothing special happens to it in memory. All that happens is that the compiler will only create certain instructions on it. That's it. x86 has no knowledge or notion of const- it's all in the compiler.

Comment: Much of what you wrote, e.g. "stack is essentially one large heap allocation" or "x86 has no notion of `const`", is badly inaccurate.  I appreciate that you're trying to explain this without talking about virtual addressing, but virtual memory really is key to how all of this works.  Especially page tables, which are where the permissions of each section are defined.  And of course all of this varies *significantly* on non-x86 processors.

Comment: I'm fully aware of virtual addressing. As you said, I'm trying to keep it simple.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK:

> Stack/Heap
>   do they use the same section of memory
>   as they can grow independently?

They can grow indipendently.

> What is this code section?

A read-only segment where code and const data are stored.

> When I have a function is it a part of the stack or
>   the code section?

The definition (code) of the function will be in the CS. The arguments of each call are passed on the stack.

> Also what is this
>   initialized/uninitialized data
>   segment?

The data segment is where globals/static variables are stored.

> Are there read only memory section
>   available?

The code segment. I suppose some OS's *might* offer primitives for creating custom read-only segments.

> When I have a const variable, what is actually happening
>   is it that the compiler marks a memory
>   section as read only or does it put
>   into a read only memory section.

It goes into the CS.

> Where are static data kept? Where are
>   global data kept?

The data segment.

Comment: Readonly segments were very popular with early Windows versions, it lets you run multiple copies of an app without using lots of scarce memory. Even the string resources ended up in shared readonly segments.

Answer (score 1):

I was in same dilemma when I was reading about memory layout's of C/C++. Here is the link which I followed to get the questions cleared.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/

The link's main illustration is added here:

[image]

I hope this helps 'the one' finding answers to similar question.

Comment: Posting link-only answers may become useless to future users of StackOverflow if the link goes dead. Try and include the important points of the link in the answer itself

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Sure to follow. This was my first answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to the answers, here is a quote from [GotW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/009.htm)   that classifies some major memory areas (note the difference between free-store, which is what I would usually refer to as the heap, and the actual heap, which is the part managed through malloc/free). The article is a bit old so I don't know if it applies to modern C++; so far I haven't found a direct contradiction.

> Const Data      The const data area stores string literals and
>                    other data whose values are known at compile
>                    time.  No objects of class type can exist in
>                    this area.  All data in this area is available
>                    during the entire lifetime of the program. Further, all
>                    of this data is read-only, and the
>                    results of trying to modify it are undefined.
>                    This is in part because even the underlying
>                    storage format is subject to arbitrary
>                    optimization by the implementation.  For
>                    example, a particular compiler may store string
>                    literals in overlapping objects if it wants to.
>
> Stack            The stack stores automatic variables. Typically
>                    allocation is much faster than for dynamic
>                    storage (heap or free store) because a memory
>                    allocation involves only pointer increment
>                    rather than more complex management.  Objects
>                    are constructed immediately after memory is
>                    allocated and destroyed immediately before
>                    memory is deallocated, so there is no
>                    opportunity for programmers to directly
>                    manipulate allocated but uninitialized stack
>                    space (barring willful tampering using explicit
>                    dtors and placement new).
>
> Free Store      The free store is one of the two dynamic memory
>                    areas, allocated/freed by new/delete.  Object
>                    lifetime can be less than the time the storage
>                    is allocated; that is, free store objects can
>                    have memory allocated without being immediately
>                    initialized, and can be destroyed without the
>                    memory being immediately deallocated.  During
>                    the period when the storage is allocated but
>                    outside the object's lifetime, the storage may
>                    be accessed and manipulated through a void* but
>                    none of the proto-object's nonstatic members or
>                    member functions may be accessed, have their
>                    addresses taken, or be otherwise manipulated.
>
> Heap            The heap is the other dynamic memory area,
>                    allocated/freed by malloc/free and their
>                    variants.  Note that while the default global
>                    new and delete might be implemented in terms of
>                    malloc and free by a particular compiler, the
>                    heap is not the same as free store and memory
>                    allocated in one area cannot be safely
>                    deallocated in the other. Memory allocated from
>                    the heap can be used for objects of class type
>                    by placement-new construction and explicit
>                    destruction.  If so used, the notes about free
>                    store object lifetime apply similarly here.
>
> Global/Static   Global or static variables and objects have
>                    their storage allocated at program startup, but
>                    may not be initialized until after the program
>                    has begun executing.  For instance, a static
>                    variable in a function is initialized only the
>                    first time program execution passes through its
>                    definition.  The order of initialization of
>                    global variables across translation units is not
>                    defined, and special care is needed to manage
>                    dependencies between global objects (including
>                    class statics).  As always, uninitialized proto-
>                    objects' storage may be accessed and manipulated
>                    through a void* but no nonstatic members or
>                    member functions may be used or referenced
>                    outside the object's actual lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: The following applies to Linux)

The stack and heap of a process both exist in the "same" part of a process's memory. The stack and heap grow towards each other (initially, when the process is started, the stack occupies the entire area that can be occupied by the combination of the stack and the heap; each memory allocation (malloc/free/new/delete) can push the boundary between the stack and the heap either up or down). The BSS section, also located on the same OS-allocated process space, is in its own section and contains global variables. Read-only data resides in the rodata section and contains such things as string literals. For example, if your code has the line:

```
char tmpStr[] = "hello";
```

Then, the portion of the source code containing "hello" will reside in the rodata section.

A good, thorough book on this is Randall E. Bryant's Computer Systems.

Comment: The stack does NOT occupy the entire address space.  In fact, it's an error to talk about "the" stack, because each thread has its own stack, and there may be additional alternate stacks for signal handling, error recovery, etc.

Comment: What I ended to say was that the stack occupies the entire address space that can be occupied by the combination of the stack and the heap.