# Why am I able to increment a pointer pointing at a single new int location? and the surprisingly it works well

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator

**What's going on here it is working but it is still ambiguous. Can anyone tell me more on this or atleast point me to some relevant Sources to know more about it**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string br="\n";
    long *a=new long;
    *++a=121;
    *++a=545454;
    *++a=232;
    std::cout<<*a<<br<<a<<std::endl;
    a--;
    //delete a;
    std::cout<<*a<<br<<a<<std::endl;
    a--;
    //delete a;
    std::cout<<*a<<br<<a<<std::endl;
    delete a;
    
    pause;//macro for windows("pause")
}
```

Comment: I guess the program was made deliberately to see the effects of handling a pointer inappropriately. From education perspective it's good to know the capability of a `long` pointer.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: Writing outside of allocated memory causes undefined behavior. It can have any effect, including no error at all.

Comment: Yeah i was actually experimenting on the use of pointer so that I could see it's extent and upsides and downsides!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working because `a` is a long pointer pointing to a memory location in heap. Heap consists of a huge chunk of memory to be used at run time. In short, While incrementing `a`, `a` points to the memory location next(may not be contiguous) to the one allocated by new.

Some References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44822977/8584523

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/

Answer (score 2):

What you do is not really a suprise, but it is not defined to go well.
When you call new with an object the heap allocator allocates some space to store your object in.
What you do is just increasing the pointer to point at some memory that is not allocated. As you noticed you can write to it, but it will cause undefined behaviour, because there could also live another object, allocated by you or you could override some datastructure used by the heap to organize its memory.
Long story short, dont write to memory you did not allocated before.

Comment: Thanks allot.That really helped allot.